# Servo motor activation with pressure sensor

Tags: servo

I need to run my servo motor within a specific pressure range, given by a pressure sensor. I don't understand how to code this. I have coded for servo motor movement but I need to activate that movement in a specific range. Please, help me.

This is my servo code:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
                // twelve servo objects can be created on most boards
int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position 

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);
  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
}

void loop() {
  for(pos = 0; pos <= 30; pos += 1) {
    // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);
    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(5); // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for(pos = 30; pos>=0; pos-=1) {
    // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);
    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(5);
    // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  delay(1500);
}
```

I need to activate this servo within a 10-70 pressure range.

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell what pressure sensor are you using, but suppose that a call to `readPressure()` will give as pressure as an `int`

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup()
{
    myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
}

void loop()
{
    int pressure = readPressure();

    if(pressure >= 10 && pressure <= 70) {
        //  Pressure is in range. Move the servo.
        for(pos = 0; pos <= 30; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
            // in steps of 1 degree
            myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
            delay(5);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
        }

        for(pos = 30; pos>=0; pos-=1) {   // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
            myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
            delay(5);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
        }
    }

    //  Wait for another 1.5 sec before next loop().
    delay(1500);
}
```

Of course, you have to complete the code with the actual sensor calls.